# How can i get the special search results of a word in txt file from a Wikipedia site using bs4/python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, wikipedia

I searched a word namely `'Monocots'` in a `Wikipedia's` special search mode page. The special search (special:WhatLinksHere) results shows [these words.](https://ta.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=special:WhatLinksHere/Monocots&limit=500) How can i write the words in a txt file. Is it possible by `BeautifulSoup4/python?` How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import bs4, requests

r = requests.get('https://ta.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=special:WhatLinksHere/Monocots&limit=500')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for li in soup.find(id='mw-whatlinkshere-list').find_all('li'):
    print(li.a['title'])
```

out:

```
கத்தூரி மஞ்சள்
கோரை
எருவை (புல்)
வார்ப்புரு:Taxonomy/Asparagus
வார்ப்புரு:Taxonomy/Asparagoideae
வார்ப்புரு:Taxonomy/Asparagaceae
வார்ப்புரு:Taxonomy/Asparagales
சாத்தாவாரி
மலையன்கிழங்கு
குழிவாழை
கருப்பன் புல்
காட்டுச்சேனை
துடைப்பப்புல்
கொண்டை ராகிசு
குறத்தி நிலப்பனை
செவ்வள்ளிக் கொடி
சாலமிசிரி
```

This is very simple task, and BS4 is right tool to use.

Comment: How to remove the brackets () with its data ? Then only we will use very much.

Comment: With [this (Asterids)](https://ta.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=special:WhatLinksHere/Asterids&limit=500), we are going to delink by relavant Tamil article. Thanks indeed for creating one of the administrative tool. No such tool before this code.